# Integrating the exponential over the area bounded by the functions $y=x$ and $y=x^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, area

Can someone please help me solve the following problem below? Thank you

Compute the integral of the function over the area bounded by the functions $y=x$ and $y=x^3$ $$f(x,y) = e^{x^2}$$

Comment: $x=x^3$ means $x\in\{0,\pm1\}$

Comment: so do we just integrate this from 0 to 1?  @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Compute the integral slice by slice. Write an expression for $A$ according to your boundaries.

Comment: so since we are bounded by +/- 1, do we plug these values in to get new lower and upper bounds? @Yourong'DZR'Zang

Comment: The second step in no_idea's answer is what I meant by integrating slice by slice. Notice that we are changing $x$ so there is no need to get new lower and upper bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

You can think about it in terms of physics. If the function $f(x,y)$ denotes the mass distribution, the mass corresponding to the area between the curves $y = x$ and $y = x^{3}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
M = \int_{D}\mathrm{d}m = \int_{D}f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y 
\end{align*}

At your case, $D = \{(x,y)\in\textbf{R}^{2}\mid (0\leq x\leq 1)\wedge(x^{3}\leq y\leq x)\}$.

Hence we have the following result:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x^{3}}^{x}e^{x^{2}}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{1}(x - x^{3})e^{x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Arguably, it should be $$D = \{(x,y)\in\textbf{R}^{2}\mid (-1\leq x\leq 0)\land (x \leq y \leq x^3) \lor (0\leq x\leq 1)\land(x^{3}\leq y\leq x)\}$$ which means the integral is off by a factor of two.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. But due to symmetry of the problem, it suffices to multiply the result by two.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. I got myself confused for no reason.